# GStreamer Python Playbin multiple video-filters

Tags: python-gstreamer

I am using the `playbin` using `gst-python`:

```
player = Gst.ElementFactory.make("playbin", None)
player.set_property("uri", "file:///tmp/big_buck_bunny_720p_30mb.mp4")
```

Now I add some video-filters:

```
videocrop = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videocrop', None)
videocrop.set_property('top', 300)
```

This nicely crops the video. I can also do this with `videoflip`. However, when I try to apply multiple filters, using a `Bin`, my pipeline does not work. Code I am using:

```
video_filters = Gst.Bin("video_filters")
videocrop = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videocrop', None)
videocrop.set_property('top', 300)
video_filters.add(videocrop)
videoflip = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoflip', None)
videoflip.set_property('method', 'clockwise')
video_filters.add(videoflip)
videocrop.link(videoflip)
player.set_property('video-filter', video_filters)
```

The pipeline won't play. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried giving a timeout between the 2 filters?  please provide some more debug info of whats happening when you try to play.

Answer (score 0):

Hey so I doubt this is the most optimal solution but something like the following worked for me.

```
video_filters = Gst.Bin("video_filters")
videocrop = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videocrop', None)
videocrop.set_property('top', 300)
video_filters.add(videocrop)
videoflip = Gst.ElementFactory.make('videoflip', None)
videoflip.set_property('method', 'clockwise')
video_filters.add(videoflip)
videocrop.link(videoflip)

sink_pad = videocrop.sinkpad
source_pad = videoflip.srcpad
ghostpad_sink = Gst.GhostPad.new("sink", sink_pad)
ghostpad_source = Gst.GhostPad.new("src", source_pad)
video_filters.add_pad(ghostpad_sink)
video_filters.add_pad(ghostpad_source)

player.set_property('video-filter', video_filters)
```

The debug log says something about the ghost pad being unnecessary

```
gstutils.c:1587:prepare_link_maybe_ghosting: filter-convert and video_filters in same bin, no need for ghost pads
```

But removing it stopped things working for me.